# Rename Multiple Images and store in in array React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on react native project. I need to upload multiple images in firebase storage and also store their details in real time data database. I tried

```
  listing.images.forEach((image) => {
    data["image"] = {
      name: "image" + Date.now(),
      type: "image/jpeg",
      uri: image,
    };
  });
```

but did not work for me. I also tried FormData();  but I can't store it in firebase.
I just want to store multiple images details (like name and format) in an array.

Comment: so data is not storing in firebase or you are not able to create proper data array?

Comment: By this approach I can get details of only one Image.

Comment: okay and can you share your expected output?

Comment: const images = {
  1: { name: "name", type: "jpeg", uri: "uri" },
  2:{name: "name", type: "jpeg", uri: "uri" },
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ordinary arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) should be avoided in the Realtime Database, you should instead store your array entries in a mapped object of some ID to the data.

In your current code, on each loop of the `forEach` you replace the existing `data.images` with the next entry in your array. You need to create new entries for each image. The "best practice" for this is to use Firebase's Push IDs, which can be generated using by calling `const key = anyRef.push().key`. Unlike `const name = "image" + Date.now()`, which can generate duplicate names if running fast enough, you won't be able to generate duplicate push IDs.

In addition, if you ever need to delete an image, you can just use the following without needing to mess with the indexes/keys of the other entries:

```
firebase.database().ref("listings")
  .child(listingId)
  .child("images")
  .child(imageId)
  .remove();
```

Applying this gives:

```
async function addListing(listing) {
  const listingsRef = firebase.database().ref("listings");
  const listingImages = {};
  
  const listingData = {
    sellerId: listing.sellerId,
    images: listingImages,
    // ...
  }

  listing.images.forEach((image) => {
    const key = listingsRef.push().key; // use firebase to generate a UUID
    listingImages[key] = {
      name: key,
      type: "image/jpeg", // <-- don't assume this
      uri: image
    }
  }

  return listingsRef.push(listingData);
}
```

Usage:

```
addListing(listing)
  .then(
    (ref) => console.log(`New listing #${ref.key} was created successfully!`),
    (err) => console.error(`Failed to create listing!`, err)
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like below:-

```
data["image"] = listing.images.map((image) => {
  return {
    name: "image" + Date.now(),
    type: "image/jpeg",
    uri: image
  }
});
```