# Error 400 Bad Request while Uploading Image to firebase storage in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am working on react native project connected to firebase. I am =using firebase storage ad=nd trying to upload a file to firebase storage But I get following error.

> `{code: 400, message: "Bad Request. Could not access bucket quickbuy-a0764.appspot.com","status":"Access_Bucket"}`

I tried configuring my permissions but did not work for me.
example of Image Uri I am providing to **put()** is as follows

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAk  and so on

Now what should I do to resolve this issue?

```
let filename = values.images + Date.now();
let uri = values.images[0];
const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${filename}`).put(uri);
  uploadTask.on("state_changed", (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`firebase.storage.Reference#put()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#put) accepts a `Blob`, `Uint8Array` or an `ArrayBuffer`. Because you are trying to upload a Data URI, which is a string, you need to use `[`firebase.storage.Reference#putString()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#putstring).

To do this for a data URI, you would use:

```
someStorageRef.putString(uri, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL);
```

Next, based on these lines:

```
const filename = values.images + Date.now();
let uri = values.images[0];
```

`values.images` is an array, which means that `filename` will end up being something similar to `"[object Object],[object Object]1620528961143"`.

As I covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67447376/3068190) on your question yesterday, this is a poor way to generate IDs as it can lead to duplicates & collisions - use a Push ID instead.

```
const uri = /* ... */;

const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
const filename = rootRef.push().key;

const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${filename}`)
  .putString(uri, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL);
uploadTask.on("state_changed", (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot);
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error on uploading file   **dataURL.match is not a function. (In 'dataURL.match(/^data:([^,]+)?,/)', 'dataURL.match' is undefined)**

Comment: and an other thing is when I try to upload image using  **const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${filename}`).put(uploadUri);**  it uplaod a file but with size 9 bytes and is not readable.

Comment: Sounds like your `uri` variable is an object, not a string. Use `.putString(String(uri), firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL)`. Make sure to follow the documentation to the letter otherwise you'll get bugs like these.

Answer (score 0):

**Future Use with Version 9 of the SDK**

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

    const uploadImage = async (values) => {
      const filename = values.images + Date.now();
      const uri = values.images[0];
      // Create a root reference
      const storage = getStorage();
        
      // Create a reference to 'images/$filename.jpg'
      const filesImagesRef = ref(storage, 1images/${filename}.jpg);
    
      await uploadBytes(filesImagesRef, uri).then((snapshot) => {
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
      });
    }
```

Let us know how this works for you!

Comment: It's worth noting that this answer makes use of the v9 Beta JavaScript SDK.

Comment: this one does not work there are a lot of warnings during compiling

Comment: like Attempted import error: 'getStorage' is not exported from 'firebase/storage'.

Comment: same with ref and uplaodBytes.

Comment: if you are using react native, you should ideally be on v9 or have support for the features there. Could you share the file where you are initializing firebase?

Comment: import firebase from "firebase/app";
import firebaseConfig from "./app/config/firebaseConfig";


if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one
}

Comment: Unless firebase was installed with `npm install --save firebase@exp`, you won't be able to use the v9 Beta SDK as shown here. Currently `npm install --save firebase` will install v8 of the SDK.

Comment: gotcha, I would say that samthecodingman answer should be more valuable to you. I think your error has something to do with how you are naming the file. I would try to be as simple as possible and put as a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to the others that couldn't fix it with the method samthecodingman provided, try to change some parameters so for example try a shorter child name. code 400 is just a sign of a bad request or in easier terms firebase doesn't like some things you sent to him. I tried to send data with a uuid which was too long and the childchange fixed it for me.